# Flip default face orientation of object

Tags: faces, normals

I'm creating my first model and it's going fine so far. One thing though - I probably did something wrong in the beginning, and default orientation (normals) of faces is pointing inside the model. I can easuly fix it with Ctr+Shift+N, to set normals to point "inside" the model, which happens to be correct in my case. However if I create a new face, sometimes it creates flipped, so it always tried the default orientation, and I have to re-calculate normals again.

Can I somehow set Blender in such a way, that what he now thinks of a "normals pointing inside the model" to "normals pointing outside", which is correct (in my case)?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand well, but you can try Alt + R to clear an object rotation, or Shift + C to set the cursor at the center.